tags field validate max count
To set the maximum number of tag fields that can be added to a tag field,   we created a custom module for validation.
I used this as a reference, but it seems to be done a little differently in craft5.
https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/976
The source code I implemented is below.
TagField was not countable, it maybe not ArrayValidator...
private function attachEventHandlers(): void
{
    Event::on(Entry::class, Entry::EVENT_DEFINE_RULES, function(DefineRulesEvent $e) {
        $entry = $e->sender;

        if ($entry->section->handle == 'mysection') {
            $e->rules[] = [
                "field:keywords", 
                ArrayValidator::class, 
                'count' => [0,5],
                'on' => Entry::SCENARIO_LIVE,
                'message' => 'You can set up to 5 keywords.'
            ];
        }else{
            return;
        }
    });
}

Please, let me know your best practice.
